# Deploying a app to kubernetes through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a app to kubernetes cluster through jenkins using `Kubernetes Continuous Deploy` plugin. I copied the config `.yml` file into jenkins machine and gave the path in the build step and I'm getting a error:

> "No matching configuration files found"

screenshots of the plugin and console out are in links.

[image: Plugin]

[image: Console output]

Comment: I guess you are missing the `/` at the begging of the config pah:
/home/.....

Comment: No, the path was supposed to be given in Ant Global syntax so I didn't give '/' in the beginning. @IdirOuhabMeskine

Comment: @srinivasb dude i've been struggling with this issue for quite some time. my problem is SSH server what server is that exactly?

Comment: @muzijack its supposed to be the Kubernetes Master Server. If you have ssh capability(ppk file), it will ssh and get the credentials it need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw same error on my jenkins server then i fixed it by correcting the path.

Can you put your .yml files to your source control. Because Kubernetes Continuous Deploy plugin will check your workspace.

And plugin will check your path and it will not find it. I attached images and you can see my working configurations.

[config path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En8jA.png)
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y17vf.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the .yml file to the github repository
2. Put the following as the path for the file
   `$workspace/deployment.yml`
3. Checkout the repository from the git url to the job's workspace.